# "Left as an exercise for the reader" vs. "to the reader"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions, to-for

I think the most common is "X is left as an exercise *for* the reader", but it looks like both are in use.

Is the "to" variant correct? If not, why?

Comment: @WillHunting Well, it's just a question that came to my mind today. But yes, it's a frequent sentence in math parlance, although I've seen it used—maybe to make fun of mathematicians—in other contexts. I'm Italian and there's two ways to translate this sentence as well, one of which corresponds to the "for" form, and the other to the "to" one. They're both correct, even though I prefer the one that would translate to the "for" form.

Comment: Are you leaving the exercise as a bequest? If so, use *to*; otherwise, favor *for*.

Comment: AND *X is left **to** the reader as an exercise (to solve)* AND *X is left as an exercise **for** the reader (to solve)** AND *X is left **to** the reader **for** solution* &c. Worms ain't got nothin on prepositions for being better left in unopened cans.

Comment: On the arXiv, google says *[for the reader](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Aarxiv.org+%22left+as+an+exercise+for+the+reader%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:unofficial&client=firefox-a)* gives 1680 hits and *to the reader* (there's not enough space in this comment to give the link, but it's trivial to modify the other link) gives 1350 hits. Use whichever you prefer.

Comment: @Peter Shor: For OP's context, the preference is a lot stronger than your figures suggest - ["as an exercise for the reader"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22as+an+exercise+for+the+reader%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1):83,700 against ["as an exercise to the reader"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22as+an+exercise+for+the+reader%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1):20,800. That's over 4:1 in favour of what OP rightly suspects is the case. To be honest, "to" there sounds decidedly "odd" to me (maybe I should get out more, or read more maths textbooks! :)

Comment: We can argue about which one edges out the other, but the fact is, both are in use, and the crux of the matter is that this is yet another instance where more than one preposition can be used without altering the meaning of the sentence very much. Nortonn S asks similar questions rather often. An exercise can be _to_ the reader (think of the exercise as a package addressed _to_ a recipient), or it can be _for_ the reader (think of it as a package left _for_ a recipient).

Comment: @FumbleFingers If you track down to the end of the hitlists, the actual numbers (not the numbers reported at the top of Google's page) are 670 and 511. The 511 authors obviously think of it not as an exercise *for* the reader but as an exercise *left to* the reader.

Comment: @StoneyB: I believe that Google stops showing hits on most queries at some random spot between 500 and 1000. I suspect that for both of these phrases, there are a lot more hits out there that Google isn't showing you.

Comment: @PeterShor  You may be right. I know on Google Books when I run out to the end the number at the top of the page abruptly changes to reflect the number of hits actually shown; so I don't trust that top number. Accordingly, I treat that number as hearsay; for evidentiary purposes, if Google won't show me the hit, it doesn't exist!

Comment: @PeterShor, StoneyB: I agree GB "guesstimates" can be wildly out. But I they're usually significant in cases like this, where only a single common word is different. The figures for **to/for** and **to the/for the** are huge, but in both cases marginally favour **to**, so if GB were just biasing its guesses on the basis of how common those particular words (or word-pairs) are, it would have jumped the other way. I don't say **to** is "wrong" (or even "rare"), but in my experience it's certainly the less common of the two in this context. GB is just (admittedly weak) support for my position.

Comment: Or as C.F. Gauss put it in Latin, "Calculum quem hic apponere nimis prolixum foret lectorum industriae committimus".

Comment: (I haven't read the answers/comments, but) use of *to* here implies "left to the reader's discretion" as I see it. Use *for* instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say the alternatives should be:

> - Left to the reader as an exercise
> - Left as an exercise for the reader

It seems to me that "to the reader" modifies "left" whereas "for the reader" could modify *left* or it could modify *exercise*. When left at the end as in the question, then I'd have to suggest that "to the reader" is incorrect.

Comment: Yes. It certainly doesn't modify itself or part of itself.

Answer (score -1):

That is basically a question about diction/meaning, not grammar: perhaps the main reason that the "basic" to has come within the last few decades to be a catchall preposition that can connect practically any two words or phrases, whether the result is awkward, sensible or not. It will not be of much use to try parsing examples. Simply look up and understand their meanings, and then use the word, to or for, that expresses the meaning you want (not wish) to convey.